# Dialog and Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar

I have a Dialog that has a ListView in it, and when you select an item a contextual actionBar needs to appear.

This is what I have so far
This is inside my Dialog's ListView adapter's getView method. searchView is the view.
bAct is my Activity that starts the dialog.

```
final LinearLayout searchView;

final LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if (convertView == null) {
    searchView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    vi.inflate(resource, searchView, true);
}
else
{
    searchView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
}

//Some code setting up some textview etc...
searchView.startActionMode(bAct.savedSearchMode);
```

And in my Activity I have

```
public ActionMode.Callback savedSearchMode = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(ActivityViewTimetable.this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.saved_searches, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.run:
                progress.setTitle("Searching...");
                progress.setMessage("Fetching classes from the server");
                progress.show();
                AsyncForTimetable(typeID, classID, venueIds.values(), true);
                hideSavedSearchDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                ToastMe("Delete search");
                break;
            default:
                ToastMe("Unknown: "+menuItem.getTitle());
                break;
        }
        actionMode.finish();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        actionMode.finish();
    }
};
```

The whole thing works once. I can open the Dialog, get the ActionBar to change to my context items, and run a search, but once I try to do it again the actionbar doesn't change.

Can anyone see what I've got wrong?

If you need any other bits of code posting let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I needed to set up the contextual bar in onCreate